# What is/means/does Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool and Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionPool

Tags: magento2.3, di, service-contract

There are new things we can see at `Magento 2.3` in `di.xml` for **service contracts**.

**let's give an example:`Magento_Cms` module**

**Like**

- `Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool`
- `Magento\Framework\EntityManager\HydratorPool`
- `Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionPool`

I've seen in those classes, data interface or  Repository interface as added arguments.

**Suppose:**

For `Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool`'s metadata, Magento add 
`Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface` as a parameter and also added entity table name and table primary key.

```
    <type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="metadata" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="entityTableName" xsi:type="string">cms_page</item>
                    <item name="identifierField" xsi:type="string">page_id</item>
                </item>
                <item name="Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="entityTableName" xsi:type="string">cms_block</item>
                    <item name="identifierField" xsi:type="string">block_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

- Now, My question is what is `Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool` and why it's needed.
- **Why add Data interface, database table name and it pk field as this class parameters.**
- **If We build a custom module(Has Database table) which has server Contract, then we need to follow this process like Cms page**

**Same Questions, I have for `Magento\Framework\EntityManager\HydratorPool`**

```
  <type name="Magento\Framework\EntityManager\HydratorPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="hydrators" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Magento\Cms\Api\Data\PageInterface" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\EntityManager\AbstractModelHydrator</item>
                <item name="Magento\Cms\Api\Data\BlockInterface" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\EntityManager\AbstractModelHydrator</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Comment: I think you can get some idea with this article: https://belvg.com/blog/eav-load-and-save-processes-in-magento-2.html Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

See this article I hope it will help you : https://black.bird.eu/en/blog/recettem2-3.html